# Sending complex object via JMS in Java

Tags: java, jms, messaging

Is it possible to send complex messages via JMS? I can send TextMessages, Messages etc .. but when I try to send my custom object type `MyObject` trough `send()` method of `MessageProducer` I get compile error.

Then I tried to cast it, I get cast exception like `MyObject cannot be cast to javax.jms.Message`

Here is a code I tried :

```
MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(destination);
messageProducer.send((Message)getMyObject()); //where getMyObject method retrieves mapped myObject type
```

anyone got any advice? thank you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As long as your object is `Serializable`, you can use an [ObjectMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/ObjectMessage.html)

```
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer( destination );
ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage( getMyObject() );
producer.send( message );
```

Comment: Is there a way to  send objects that are not serializable? I remember reading somewhere that this was possible!

Comment: You can transform your object in a json

Answer (score 0):

You have one of two problems:

1. MyObject does not implement javax.jms.Message
2. getMyObject does not return a MyObject (assuming that it does implement Message)